# GCE "create-with-container --container-mount-disk" flag mounts disk as read-only

Tags: mongodb, docker, google-compute-engine, gce-persistent-disk

I am trying to use a Percona Docker image for MongoDB on GCE, however I'm running into an issue with Mongo saying the mounted path is read-only. I looked around as much as I could, but im stumped at what could be the issue.

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container mongo-svr \
--create-disk name=disk-1,size=1GB \
--container-mount-disk mount-path="/data/mongodb",mode=rw \
--container-image=docker.io/percona/percona-server-mongodb:4.2
```

I used the above command and it creates my instance. I then SSH into the server, connect to the running mongo instance to shutdown, then I run: `docker exec -it [NAME] mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --dbpath=/data/mongodb --bind_ip localhost`

This spits out an error stating:

```
CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "localhost" }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" }, sharding: { clusterRole: "configsvr" }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/mongodb" } }
STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/mongodb, terminating
```

At this point, I've been recreating instances with different params, but nothing has worked so far. Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

**Updated with command output**

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container mongo-config-f --zone us-central1-f --create-disk name=disk-1,size=1GB --container-mount-disk mount-path="/data/mongodb" --container-image=docker.io/percona/percona-server-mongodb:4.2 --machine-type=f1-micro
WARNING: Default device-name for disk name [disk-1] will be [disk-1] because it is being mounted to a container with [`--container-mount-disk`]
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/zones/us-central1-f/instances/mongo-config-f].
NAME            ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
mongo-config-f  us-central1-f  f1-micro                   xx.xx.xx.xx  xx.xx.xx.xx     RUNNING
```

Comment: I'm aware that ```mode=rw``` isn't needed, but wanted to be explicit since nothing was working. Running the command with/without it results in the same thing. As for the mount, /data/mongodb isn't mounted. However, my understanding is that the name you use for ```--create-disk``` (disk-1) will result in ```/mnt/disks/gce-containers-mounts/gce-persistent-disks/disk-1``` which will be the mounting point for the docker container, mapping internally to ```/data/mongodb```. So calling ```mount``` won't show that path, but the ```/mnt/disks/``` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your issue on my test project and found that:

- persistent disk was created and mounted in read-write mode as expected;

  ```
  bash-4.2$ mount 
  ...
  /dev/sdb on /data/mongodb type ext4 (rw,relatime)
  ```
- docker runs containers inside our VM properly;
- the cause of the error while running `docker exec -it [NAME] mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --dbpath=/data/mongodb --bind_ip localhost` is permissions inside mongodb container:

  ```
  bash-4.2$ ls -l /data/        
  ...
  drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root 4096 Feb 19 15:33 mongodb
  ```

**As a workaround commands could be executed with root permissions**:

```
$ docker exec -it --user root klt-mongo-svr-upd-wowt mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --db path=/data/mongodb
```

Please find more details and my steps below:

1. create VM:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create-with-container mongo-svr \
   --create-disk name=disk-1,size=1GB \                                                                                 
   --container-image docker.io/percona/percona-server-mongodb:4.2 \
   --container-mount-disk mount-path="/data/mongodb"                               
   WARNING: Default device-name for disk name [disk-1] will be [disk-1] because it is being mounted to a container with [`--container-mount-disk`]
   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/mongo-svr].
   NAME           ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
   mongo-svr-upd  europe-west3-a  n1-standard-1               10.156.0.9   35.XXX.155.XXX  RUNNING
   ```
2. SSH to instance;
3. check if container is running:

   ```
   $ docker ps
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
   dfad9c10235d        percona/percona-server-mongodb:4.2                                   "/entrypoint.sh mong…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       klt-mongo-svr-upd-wowt
   bbe02c8e8621        gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:0.2-1.5.33-1-1   "/entrypoint.sh /usr…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       stackdriver-logging-agent
   ```

   everything looks good at this point;
4. try to run command as user:

   ```
    $ docker exec -it klt-mongo-svr-upd-wowt mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --dbpath=/data/mongodb --bind_ip localhost
   ```

   and observe the same error:

   ```
   2020-02-19T15:37:53.176+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/mongodb, terminating
   ```

   here key **read-only directory: /data/mongodb**;
5. check mounts and permissions inside of the container:

   ```
   $ docker exec -it klt-mongo-svr-upd-wowt /bin/bash
   bash-4.2$ mount 
   ...
   /dev/sdb on /data/mongodb type ext4 (rw,relatime)
   ...
   ```

   as we expected **disk was created and mounted in read-write mode** to the container

   ```
   bash-4.2$ ls -l /data/        
   total 8
   drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb root 4096 Feb 19 15:36 db
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root 4096 Feb 19 15:33 mongodb
   bash-4.2$
   ```

   but to work with `/data/mongodb` you need `root` permissions;
6. try to run command as root:

   ```
   $ docker exec -it --user root klt-mongo-svr-upd-wowt mongod --configsvr --replSet rs0 --dbpath=/data/mongodb
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.970+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.973+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=119 port=27019 dbpath=/data/mongodb 64-bit host=mongo-svr-upd
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.2-3
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2cdb6e50913583f627acc5de35dc4e04dbfe196f
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.974+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.975+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.975+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.975+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { replication: { replSet: "rs0" }, sharding: { clusterRole: "configsvr" }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/mongodb" } }
   2020-02-19T15:45:24.976+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
   ...
   ```

   and **it's working with root permissions**.